# Rake db:migrate missing :controller

Tags: mysql, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake

I'm very confused about this error message, I'm completely unaware of any missing controllers yet this is the error it's spitting out
[image]

There's a little more that's cut off but I really hope that helps, this is a really frustrating error.

Comment: More info would help...is this a fresh install?  Off hand it looks like something is wrong with your rails...

Comment: No it's not a fresh install, it's slightly used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have invalid routes. When you run `rake db:migrate`, it loads the entire Rails environment, so if there's an error while loading, there will be an error while migrating.

Post your `routes.rb` file if you need help fixing your routes.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue, thanks a ton!